# Custom feeds action in WordPress blog

Tags: wordpress, rss, blogs, feed

I want to use WordPress for my blog. I will install it in my local machine. I know that it has RSS feeds with links. But I have 2 confused problems.

- When my number of feeds is very big, assume 10.000.000. I want to limit the number of results when load RSS feed with a request's format as:

> http://[myblog_domain]/[rss_name]?limit=25
>   
>   to limit to top 25 results. May be 25,30, 40, ... or any integer for the limit parameter. Are there any way to do that?

- Another problem, I want to load a range of RSS items with a request's format as:

> http://[myblog_domain]/[rss_name]?from=31&count=10
>   
>   to load 10 RSS items begining from the 30th one. May be any integer for the 2 parameters: from, count. Are there any way to do that?

Thank you!

**UPDATE 1**: about limit parameter

I see there's one while loop in the feed_rss2.php file with the format as:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      // Your loop code
endwhile;
```

It iterate the post. It already has the limit referring to admin's setting section in the web: Setting / Reading / Syndication feeds show the most recent

I guess that I need to modify this iteration to fit my expectation when the url is passed the parameter (limit = 25, assume) .

How can I do it? Thank you!

**UPDATE 2**: Or Are there any plugins of this purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that in wordpress, read below article first

http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds\

So you can modify the rss output template and dealing with the arguments

Comment: Dear, thanks for your support! Please consider my update for more information of my expectation. Please help me.